# Survey database design

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Wish you a peaceful and healthy new year. **

I am working on a survey database design for mysql/php/wordpress for estimated **10,000,000 users**. Each user will eventually answer about **5,000 questions** over a course of several years. These questions are answered mainly as scale of : AGREE, NEUTRAL, DISAGREE, DONT KNOW as multiple choice answers. There is no right or wrong answer. A user would be able to attempt the questions again in the future. Also, at each attempt his/her answer_record gets updated with new data. Would the following database design be reasonable from database performance and data normalization perspective? Thank you in advance.

TABLE_USER:

- user_id
- username
- user_email
- [other user specific fields]

TABLE_QUESTION:

- question_id
- question_text
- question_image
- question_category1  [A question may exist in more than 1 category]
- question_category2
- question_category3

TABLE_ANSWER:

- answer_id
- user_id
- question_id
- answer_agree
- answer_neutral
- answer_disagree
- answer_dontknow
- answered_datetime
- answer_number_of_attempts

Sincerely,

Harrison.

Comment: this should be moved to the db design forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of proper db design means stepping back and making sure that if you added one more thing, you wouldn't have to redesign the tables, and also that discrete types of information are separated out. If several columns are doing the same thing (but recording different answers) you should split them out into another table and have a single link table.

Also, do you really need to say Table in the table name? of course it's a table, what else would it be?

TABLE_USER is fine

for TABLE_QUESTION you should drop the category columns, instead make a new table

TABLE_CATEGORIES
with information on the different categories

and have another table

CATEGORIES_PER_QUESTION

- question_id
- category_id

that allows a question to have any number of categories, you can look which ones each question has by querying categories_per_question

TABLE_ANSWER should be split into two tables,

RESPONSE

- response_id
- user_id
- question_id
- answer_id
- datetime_responded

and ANSWERS

- answer_id
- answer_name

Where answer name is AGREE, NEUTRAL, DISAGREE, DONT KNOW or any other sort of answer you might provide.

If you wanted to be fancy, you could even have another join table between ANSWERS and TABLE_QUESTION, indicating what answers will be available per question.

To know the number of attempts, and other information I dropped, you can query the DB so it doesn't need a column for itself.

Comment: Hi Serakfalcon, Your answer has been very helpful. Certainly, I do not need to write tablet names with TABLE prefix. :) I will separate tables per your recommendations. Considering the user numbers, do you anticipate any performance problems? Sincerely.

Comment: Performance depends on lots of variables, largely the server the database is hosted on, and how queries are built, so it's really hard to say in advance, you just have to test that sort of thing.

Comment: To whoever -1'd this question, well, excuse me for not talking about database normalization & first & second normal forms but I was trying to keep things simple for the OP

Answer (score 0):

I realize you want help with DB design, but even if the design is perfect, this will fail to scale reasonable if your system is not planned properly for scaling (BIG).

A proper designed API can scale endlessly.

With those numbers it will be cheaper overtime to have this external and build an API for it so you can scale properly. Building something directly into WordPress will require you to scale to quickly in all directions just for running PHP, HTTP and MySQL.

If you build an API in between WordPress and your survey database you can then scale MySQL and build any number of systems in between, Memcache, search engines, etc...

This will give you better separation between your systems allowing for more efficient scaling.
Scaling each only when it needs it.

So I would plan your system/infrastructure at this point also.

Comment: Hi Topdown, by using Wordpress core/plugins, I am able to manage 90% services/features. However, due to lacking 10% of services/features in Wordpress, I am working on developing a survey engine API using MySQL, & PHP. By controlling randomization, I am hoping the API would also allow me to improve performance reduce server load.